# OpportunityLineItem in test classes

Tags: apex, unit-test, standard-objects, opportunity-lineitem

I am trying to insert OpportunityLineItem record in my test class but unable to insert.

```
Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Test');
insert acc;

Opportunity oppObj = new Opportunity(Name = 'TestOpp',AccountID = acc.Id,Amount = 2000,CloseDate=Date.today(),StageName='Close Won',Type='New Customer');
insert oppObj;

Product2 newProd = new Product2(Name = 'test product', family = 'test family');
insert newProd;

PriceBookEntry pbEntry = new PriceBookEntry(
    UnitPrice = 300,
    PriceBook2Id = [select id from PriceBook2 where isStandard = true].Id,
    Product2Id = newProd.Id,
    IsActive = true);

insert pbEntry ;

OpportunityLineItem oppLine = new OpportunityLineItem(pricebookentryid=pbEntry.Id,TotalPrice=2000,Quantity = 2,OpportunityID = oppObj.Id);
insert oppLine;
```

[select id from PriceBook2 where isStandard = true] is not returning any data.

any idea how to insert OpportunityLineItem.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of of this:

```
Pricebook = [select id from PriceBook2 where isStandard = true].Id
```

Why not try this instead?

```
PriceBook2Id = Test.getStandardPricebookId()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Programmable Medley, your suggestion worked !!

Comment: Glad I can help. Please make sure to mark that you excepted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is not working in your test class is because to run SOQL query on data in org use need to annotate the Test class with SeeAllData=true. Else you can use Test.getStandardPricebookId(); to get ID of the standard price book in your organization regardless of whether the test can query organization data (irrespective of the state of SeeAllData).

Comment: Please note: You should avoid using the `SeeAllData=true` as much as possible. There are numerous issues with it and should only be used as a last resort - which is very, __very__ rare.

Comment: Thanks @nevrekar_amey for your suggestion and quick reply i appreciate.
When i am using SeeAllData=true then getting duplicate record error on second run for few records so using Test.getStandardPricebookId() approch.

Comment: I concur with @programmable Medley suggestion regarding SeeAllData = true , to be avoided as much as possible.