# pricebook entry is in a different pricebook than the one assigned to the opportunity

Tags: apex, unit-test, opportunity-lineitem, pricebook

Could some body please help me on this? I am improving test coverage and below is my code:

```
static testmethod void opportunityLineItem_Test(){
    Id priceBookID = Test.getStandardPricebookId();

    Opportunity oppObj = new Opportunity(Name='test opportunity',StageName = 'Pending Renewal', CloseDate = Date.newInstance(2015, 06, 30));
    insert oppObj;

    Product2 testPrd = new Product2(IsActive=true,Name='test Product',Description='Description for test Product');
    insert testPrd;

    PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry(IsActive=true,Pricebook2Id=priceBookID,Product2Id=testPrd.Id,UnitPrice=10.00);  
    insert pbe;

    OpportunityLineItem oli = new OpportunityLineItem(OpportunityId = oppObj.Id, PricebookEntryId = pbe.Id, Quantity = 10.00, ServiceDate = Date.newInstance(2015, 06, 24),totalPrice = 20.00);
    insert oli; //It is failing on this line

}
```

The error I am receiving is : `System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, field integrity exception: unknown (pricebook entry is in a different pricebook than the one assigned to the opportunity): [unknown]`

My code is same as the one in this post([OpportunityLineItem in test classes](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/72497/opportunitylineitem-in-test-classes)) but not sure why this is still failing.

**EDIT:** I just noticed that I have a process running on opportunity object, which will assign a default price book whenever a new opportunity object is inserted. This is why my test is failing saying..

Comment: Are you sure you are running this test class, when I copy paste the exact code I do not see any issues/

Comment: Yes, I am running in test class.

Comment: can you paste your developer console and the debug log

Comment: @rao Your guess is correct. There is nothing wrong with the code. I just edited the question. I wish i could accept your comment as answer :)

Comment: This was an unique scenario I would have not guessed unless looking carefully at the debug log. Answer this question and mark your answer solved for the benefit of others who come looking for answers.

Comment: What does Test.getStandardPricebookId(); return?

Comment: @MosheKarmel please post this as a new question, You can google about getStandardPricebookId() in salesforce and it should take you to the documentation right away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Opportunity needs to have pricebook2Id set

```
Opportunity oppObj = new Opportunity(Name='test opportunity',
                                     StageName = 'Pending Renewal', 
                                     pricebook2Id = pricebookId,  // ***
                                     CloseDate = Date.newInstance(2015, 06, 30));
```

In the UI, when you add Opportunity Products, you must select a pricebook and SFDC updates the Opportunity record with that value before you can add OLI

**Other things to think about:**

If you use custom pricebooks, you need PBE for both the standard Pricebook and the custom pricebook

If using multi currencies; the Opportunity currency has to be the same as all OLI currencies on that Oppo.

Comment: Even after adding the pricebookID to the opportunity object, I am still getting the same error. Also I noticed that the link I posted in the question does not have any pricebook assigned to the opportunity object but looks like it might have worked him but mine is failing.

Comment: I don't think the answer is correct. It doesn't work for me I am still getting same error described in above issue